# Is possible to set record from OpportunityHistory or OpportunityFieldHistory for legacy records

Tags: reporting, import, system-permissions

Before starting to use Salesforce, users were using Excel to control Opportunity pipeline. Now that they are using Salesforce, they need a report that displaying for how long they (old) Opportunities were in each stage.

We imported in Salesforce the old opportunities (that were in excel), but there is an way to set the `OpportunityFieldHistory` or `OpportunityHistory` so the data in Salesforce can reflect what was in excel and the users create the required reports?

Comment: As of the time of this comment, this is still an [open idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdhWtUAJ/ability-to-overwrite-createdate-during-opportunityhistory-import). You may want to vote on it to be notified when/if it is released.

Comment: I've only seen this done by importing the data into a custom object (child of Opportunity) then writing an LWC, screen flow, or VF page to "merge" at run-time the OOTB related list with the historical related list